# Calculate only lower triangular elements of a matrix OR calculation on all possible pairs of the elements of a vector with jax

Tags: python, jax

Is it possible to efficiently run some calculation on all possible pairs of the elements of a vector? I.e. I want to fill the lower triangular elements of a matrix (possibly flattened).

I.e. I want to:

- calculate `do_my_calculation(input_vector[i], input_vector[j])`
- for all i, j in [1, `length(input_vector)`] **and** j < i
- save all the results

The shape of the results is not terribly important. If I can choose however, I would prefer a vector corresponding to an unrolled of the triangular (i, j) matrix however.

To illustrate what I would like to do in pseudo-python:

```
input_vector = np.arange(100)
result_vector = []

for i in range(1, len(input_vector)):
    for j in range(0, i):
        result_vector.append(do_my_calculation(input_vector[i], input_vector[j])
```

Note: For this question, the types of `input_vector` and `result_vector` in the above code are not pertinent. Equally, I am of course happy to preallocate result_vector if required. I am using a list for the sake of conciseness of the sample code.

## Edit 1: concrete example as requested by @ddejohn

Note: The question is not whether I can get this to run in jax but whether I can get it to run efficiently, i.e. vectorized .

```
# Set up the problem
import numpy as np

dim = 15
input_vector_x = np.random.rand(dim)
input_vector_y = np.random.rand(dim)
output_vector = np.empty(np.tril_indices(dim, k=-1)[0].size)

assert input_vector_x.size == input_vector_y.size

# alternative implementation 1
counter = 0
for i in range(1, input_vector_x.size):
    for j in range(0, i):
        output_vector[counter] = (input_vector_y[j] - input_vector_y[i]) / (input_vector_x[j] - input_vector_x[i])
        counter += 1

# alternative implementation 2

indices = np.tril_indices(dim, k=-1)
i = indices[0]
j = indices[1]

output_vector = (input_vector_y[j] - input_vector_y[i]) / (input_vector_x[j] - input_vector_x[i])
```

Comment: Please "illustrate" with a concrete example.

Comment: @ddejohn Ok, I will ammend the question shortly.

Comment: @ddejohn Please see the ammended question.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. Your post should include a simple, minimal example of an input and the expected output. All I see when running your code is a jumble of numbers. Can you provide more detail on exactly what calculation you want to perform on these... combinations? Are you trying to apply *any* arbitrary binary function over the pairwise combinations of elements of a vector?

Comment: @ddejohn I am not sure what you are asking for. I think we have a communication problem. You want me to hand calculate a concrete example? How does this help? The simplest form of my question is as follows: "How can I use jax to calculate some function `fn(x1, x2)` for all possible pairs of elements of a vector `x`?" So I think, yes, I want to "apply any arbitrary binary function over the pairwise combinations of elements of a vector" in a vectorized/batched manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this. If you want to compute the full matrix of pairwise results, you could use typical numpy-style broadcasting, assuming your function supports it. Similarly, you could use JAX's [Automatic Vectorization (`vmap`)](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/03-vectorization.html) functionality whether or not your function is compatible with broadcasting.

If you really wish to only compute each value once, you can do this using the lower or upper triangular indices. Note that although this performs fewer operations, you may find that in practice it's faster, particularly on accelerators like GPU and TPU, to compute the full result. The reason for this is that multi-dimensional indexing (the `gather` operation) is generally relatively expensive on this kind of hardware, so the overhead of doubling the number of function calls may be preferable.

Here's a demonstration of these three approaches:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

key = jax.random.PRNGKey(5748395)
dim = 3
x = jax.random.uniform(key, (dim,))

def f(x1, x2):
  return (x1 * x2) / (x1 + x2)

# Option 1: full result, broadcasted operations
print(f(x[:, None], x[None, :]))
# [[0.34950745 0.00658672 0.28704265]
#  [0.00658672 0.00332469 0.00655982]
#  [0.28704265 0.00655982 0.24352014]]

# Option 2: full result, via vmap
f_mapped = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(f, (None, 0)), (0, None))
print(f_mapped(x, x))
# [[0.34950745 0.00658672 0.28704265]
#  [0.00658672 0.00332469 0.00655982]
#  [0.28704265 0.00655982 0.24352014]]

# Option 3: explicitly computing at lower-triangular indices
i, j = jnp.tril_indices(dim)
out_tril = f(x[i], x[j])
print(out_tril)
# [0.34950745 0.00658672 0.00332469 0.28704265 0.00655982 0.24352014]

print(jnp.zeros((dim, dim)).at[i, j].set(out_tril))
# [[0.34950745 0.         0.        ]
#  [0.00658672 0.00332469 0.        ]
#  [0.28704265 0.00655982 0.24352014]]
```